# How do I find the time it took for a request to complete from the cqlsh trace output?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to understand the trace of a C* read query .

My question is, looking at a trace for a read query how can I understand at what millisecond the result is available to the client.

Let's take the below snippet as an example :-

which among the following lines indicates the time at which the result is available to client

```
6148914691236517204)] | 16:36:52,764 | 127.0.0.3 | 4891
Scanned 1 rows and matched 1 | 16:36:52,765 | 127.0.0.3 | 6418
Enqueuing response to /127.0.0.1 | 16:36:52,765 | 127.0.0.3 | 6460
Sending message to /127.0.0.1 | 16:36:52,765 | 127.0.0.3 | 6874
Message received from /127.0.0.3 | 16:36:52,766 | 127.0.0.1 | 17470
Processing response from /127.0.0.3 | 16:36:52,766 | 127.0.0.1 | 17703
Executing seq scan across 0 sstables for (max(6148914691236517204), min(-9223372036854775808)] | 16:36:52,767 | 127.0.0.1 | 18473
Scanned 1 rows and matched 1 | 16:36:52,767 | 127.0.0.1 | 18681
Request complete | 16:36:52,768 | 127.0.0.1 | 19293
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The result is available at this line:

```
Scanned 1 rows and matched 1 | 16:36:52,767 | 127.0.0.1 | 18681
```

from 18681µs onward the result is sent to the client.
Also, the trace should be in µs not ms.

Comment: Thanks Paul, does this log statement "Scanned 1 rows and matched 1" only mean that the read has been successful by satisfying the given CL. 
Should we also consider the subsequent activities to call a completed request?
In that case the "Request Complete" indicates the actual time when the response is visible to the client.

Comment: Correct, the specified line is when the CL was satisfied and the result was ready for the client, the 'request complete' line should also be considered if you want to know the time it took to deliver the result to the client.  Also keep in mind Erick's answer and know that tracing an app that isn't local to the node will yield different results.

Answer (score 0):

What you are interested in is the `Request complete` activity. In your case, it took just over 19 milliseconds (`19293` microseconds) for the request to complete.

Note that cqlsh is also a client which happens to be a Python application so it is not quite going to be the same as a deployed application because those tend to be running on another server that is not co-located with the Cassandra nodes. Cheers!